# Textmate error running commands after Yosemite upgrade

Tags: ruby, textmate, rbenv, textmate2, osx-yosemite

I recently upgraded my Mac to Yosemite, and now many Textmate 2 commands that I used to use all the time are failing and giving the following error—in this example I tried to run the "Comment line" command by pressing ⌘/:

[image: Error message]

The same thing happens for "Run", "Toggle String / Symbol", and many other Textmate commands.

When I click "Edit Command", it takes me to a script the first line of which is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby18
```

If I take the `18` off of that, it seems to work, but I would have to do it for every command. There must be a better way.

I use rbenv and long ago I set my TM_RUBY variable to `$HOME/.rbenv/shims/ruby`, but setting or unsetting that doesn't seem to make a difference now. I also tried adding that path to TM's PATH variable. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out an answer. Running `ruby18` at the command line produced a "command not found" error. So I created a symlink to the system ruby (which is ruby 2.0) with that name:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/ruby /usr/local/bin/ruby18
```

That seems to have worked. Still not sure if that's the best solution. Open to any other ideas.